# Error in push notification without using authentication in worklight

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create a demo on push notification in worklight. I am new to worklight . Can i do push notification to a android device without authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i got no answer for this question for more thant 10 month and i had time to solve the doubt, I am posting the answer

Yes we can do by using Persistent cookie authentication that doesnt want any interaction with the user . The persistent cookie authentication is a header based authentication .

I found the answer from the following stackoverflow question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542930/worklight-push-notification-without-user-id
```