# userID in getUserNotificationSubscription WORKLIGHT Pushnotification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am implementing push notification in my IBM worklight project. Sample code in developerworks do it with some authentication challenger mechanism to do the subscription. I somehow used the same Authentication challenge to do the subscription (although my app design doesn't need to do this). In the sample code actual trigger of notification call is not written.

I found out from web resource that WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription(eventSourceName, userId) need to be used to get the subscribed user details. However I don't know how to get userId details here? Please let me know what is userId here and how to get its value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is information regarding `WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscripion`:

> **getUserNotificationSubscription:**
>
> getUserNotificationSubscription(eventSource, userId) Returns a
>   subscription object for a user. Returns a subscription object for the
>   user with the specified ID to the specified event source.
>
> Parameters:
>       eventSource - Mandatory. A string containing the name of the event source. 
>       userId - Mandatory. A string containing the user ID, created during the login process. The user ID can be obtained by calling
>   WL.Server.getActiveUser.
>
> Returns:
>       The method returns a subscription object that contains the user ID and the mutable subscription state.
>       Example: {userId: 'bjones', state: {numCoupons: 3}}
>
> Note:
>       All subscription object fields are read-only, except for the user subscription state. You can modify the user subscription state in your
>   JavaScript code, and then must use the save method to save it to the
>   IBM® Worklight® database.

As you can see the userId is the specific user that was created during the login and authentication process. Worklight provides a server side API WL.Server.getActiveUser() which allows you to retrieve the current user.

In regards to your other statement saying "in the sample code actual trigger of notification call is not written. " Worklight actually provides a jar file inside of the sample project that allows you to trigger the notification. Here is some more information for this backend emulation:

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have question on why I need to go through login and authentication process to do push notification. My app doesn't need to do the login. Any thoughts on this will help me understand the need of authentication challenger here better.

Comment: So in order to know what user to send the push notification to you are required to have some kind of user structure. If you do not need the user to login you will still need some kind of structure in order to specify a user. There is another post I will point you to that shows a mechanism using a persistent cookie to accomplish this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542930/worklight-push-notification-without-user-id