# Worklight send push notifications without username

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to create an application which have 2 modes: non-logged-in and logged-in (having username).

I want to send push notifications to devices in both modes. The non-logged-in devices should receive notifications such as general announcements, new events, etc. The logged-in mode devices will also receive same notifications and few more.

Now what I want to do is to subscribe the device to receive notifications for non-logged-in mode then once the user logs in to his account from that device I want to unsubscribe the previous non-logged-in notifications.

I've read the answer to this question : [Worklight: Push notification without User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542930/worklight-push-notification-without-user-id) I think that I can play with `onUserSubscribe` callback when registering the user and unsubscribe the userId of the persistent cookie. 
Is this a good idea ? Is there another suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thinking is that you could register an app to 2 event sources.

- The first event source will handle the general notifications that an app should receive, whether a user is logged-in or not.
- The second event source will handle the notifications for logged-in users.

When the app launches, subscribe to the first event source.
When the user decides to log-in, subscribe to the second event.

You should allow the user to unsubscribe from both if s/he so chooses, as well.

Additional information:

- [IBM Worklight 6.1 Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp): search for "push notifications"
- [Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Idan. Eveything is ok but the user can unsubscribe from events notifications (which is a general notification). If I'll manage subscriptions from the first event source, it will be related to the device and not to the user. I want a mechanism that maps between a user and device ID once a user logs in to the device and deletes the subscription from the first Event Source. This could be done in the callbacks (adapter side). Does this sound a good design ?

Comment: I think that if it works for your scenario, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to achieve is push notifications broadcast (send to all users). This is something that you'll be able to do with upcoming Worklight 6.2 release. You will not have to subscribe users according to username, but will be able to specify tags during subscription. And after that you'll be able to send push notifications according to this tags.

Comment: Thank you Anton. Actually I'm developing a separate system parallel which makes access to the database with heavy business logic. Users registry will be maintained by the backend and I'll share a notifications table with WL. By the way do you have a list of features of WL 6.2 ? Is it going to be ready by june?

Comment: You can try googling it, this is what I've found - http://www.websphereusergroup.org/go/article/view/articles/265479/impact_2014:_mobile_strategy_and_ibm_worklight_6.2

Comment: Planned availability date is June 13th: http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS214-124